# Dojox DataGrid: achieve row selection only by Checkboxes

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I created a DOJO 1.6 DataGrid with CheckboxSelector as shown in the tutorials.
Now I want to disable the onSelectionChanged event for rows, if they are clicked.
This event should only be fired, if the checkbox is clicked.

How can that be achieved? Is there a constructor property i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `onRowClick` method to not do the selection logic.

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    store: store,
    structure: layout,
    onRowClick: function(e){
       this.edit.rowClick(e);
       //this.selection.clickSelectEvent(e);
    }
  },
  node
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/byfaf/

Answer (score 0):

"**SelectionChanged**"` even is available. so code like this:-

```
grid.on("SelectionChanged", function(event)
    { 
        var rowId = event.rowIndex;
        grid.selection.setSelected(rowId, true);
        grid.render();
     }
```

for example please see [this](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/working_grid/demo/selector.html)